# How do you find the sum of certain elements in a 2D array? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, methods

**I have an assignment that wants me to write the method for finding the average of a category of numbers in a 2D array. Basically,**

Write the method categoryAverage. This method returns a double representing the average (arithmetic mean) of the average ages that correspond to a given age category, such that categoryAverage returns −1.0 if none of the individual ages corresponds to the given category.

For example, given the following two-dimensional arrays:

individualAges:

```
              5 43 13 16 28
             43 15 35 10 21
```

ageCategory:

```
                 C A T T Y
                 A T A C Y
```

The method call categoryAverage("T") would return the number 14.67, which is the average of the three ages that correspond to the "T" category for teenagers.

The method call categoryAverage("S") would return −1.0 because none of the ageCategory elements are equal to S.

Complete the method categoryAverage. Be sure to include the method header.

**I have no idea how to start this assignment. How would I write this method?**

Comment: If you have no idea where to begin, it would be a good idea to ask your instructor

Comment: How would you do it if they all were A?

Comment: There is a data structure suited for this task. `java.util.Map`. Specifically, `Map<String, List<Integer>>`

Comment: I'll second @QBrute's "talk to your instructor" suggestion.  Since this is a class assignment, the purpose is to have you familiarize yourself with specific concepts that are being covered in your class.  And while many of us here could write code that accomplishes the task, there's no guarantee that we'd do so in a way that uses the concepts that the assignment has been designed to reinforce, which could have a negative impact on your education and your mastery of programming concepts.

Comment: You should meet Bignum, because he posted exactly the same homework ten minutes before you.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen The A is for adult, and that would take the average of all the numbers 18-60.

Comment: @closetphilosopher Yes.  Demonstrate how you would code THAT.  Then you can get help generalizing to the A-B-C case